# Maximal pairwise intersections between a square and two ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> What is the maximum number of *pairwise* intersections between a square and two ellipses?

Two ellipses can intersect in at most four points, but that's all I have within me…

Comment: You can get 12 pretty easily, and with a bit of finesse that can go up to 20...

Answer (score 1):

Note that two ellipses can cross in at most four points, and that a line segment can cross an ellipse in at most two points. It follows that the maximal number of pairwise intersections between two ellipses and a square is $2\cdot4\cdot2+4=20$.

Here is an arrangement that achieves that maximum.
[image]